# python global variable changes unexpectedly

Tags: python-3.x, logging, global-variables

I have this code that is supposed to log to a memory variable:
(the_message_lines):

```
import logging
from thompcoutils import log_utils

the_message_lines = []


class MemoryHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    """
    Handler that keeps all log messages in memory until the beginning of the day or the size exceeds a value
    """

    def emit(self, record: logging.LogRecord):
        global the_message_lines
        try:
            msg = self.format(record)
            the_message_lines.append(msg)
            self.flush()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except:
            self.handleError(record)

    @staticmethod
    def get_lines():
        return the_message_lines

    @staticmethod
    def reset_lines():
        global the_message_lines
        the_message_lines.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_utils.load_log_config('logging.ini')
    logger = log_utils.get_logger()

    logger.warning('beginning')
    for i in range(3):
        lines = MemoryHandler.get_lines()
        logger.warning('remaining %d seconds', i, extra={'same_line':True})
    logger.warning('end')

    for line in MemoryHandler.get_lines():
        print(line)
```

It behaves as it should but the_message_lines come and go(?)

If I put a break point in the emit method and observe the_message_lines, it behaves as it should, accumulating log messages every time.
If I put a break point in the loop that is logging, the_message_lines is empty every time!
So, between log requests, the_message_lines appears to delete itself, but in the emit, it is fine.
At the end of the main() method, get_lines() returns an empty array.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is the main() method?

Comment: Apparently `reset_lines` gets called. I didn't quite understand why this is surprising.

Comment: As an aside, you really should just be using an instance variable instead of a global variable. Also note, `global the_message_lines` is not required, and should be removed

Comment: @mkrieger1, this is the main function: if __name__ == '__main__':

Comment: @mkrieger1 I can remove reset_lines and nothing changes (it is never called)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If I use an instance variable it will definitely go away when the object goes away.   I need it to persist between calls from various other files and I only want a single instance of the_message_lines so that all log calls will add to the same one.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "global" is required in a function that changes a global variable (not necessary if it is only referencing it)

Comment: @jordanthompson `global` is required to **assign** to a global variable, you *are* merely only referencing it. Just try it for yourself, remove it and your code will work exactly the same